# How to configure PasswordHasher<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

I don't understand how to use the IOptions interface to configure the PasswordHasher

this doesn't build:

```
var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<User>(new PasswordHasherOptions() { CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2 });
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you will add the build full error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're not returning the same type it expects.

Here is a typical example

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(opt =>
    {
        opt.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2;
    });

    // Rest of ConfigureServices here
}
```

And for Azure Functions

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2;
        });

        // Rest of Configure here
    }
}
```

Comment: I m using it stand alone in azure functions to verify old password stored in database in v2 version. How can I get this IServiceCollection?

Comment: Almost the same, I've edited the answer, but the code haven't been tested